# attaching the callback parameter of google plus button dynamically

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I have a google plus button with the normal code

```
<g:plusone size="tall" callback="plusone_vote" href="http://example.com"></g:plusone>
```

and I have a function

```
function plusone_vote(gpovote) {

               var gpoaction = 'Google +1 Vote';
               if (gpovote.state=='off')
                {  
                  console.log("unlike");
               }else{
                  console.log("like");
               }
               var href = gpovote.href;
}
```

Things are pretty fine until now. Whenever a gplus click is happening the console.log s are working perfectly.

but, when I am doing like this

```
<g:plusone size="tall" href="http://example.com"></g:plusone>
```

And then attaching the "callback" attribute like the following (after document.load)

```
var gplus_event = document.getElementsByTagName("g:plusone");
       if(gplus_event!=null)
       {
               console.log(gplus_event);
               var x = document.getElementsByTagName("g:plusone");
               x[0].setAttribute('callback', 'plusone_vote');
               console.log(gplus_event);

       }
```

With the two console.log inside the if(gplus_event != null) block it is shown that the "callback" attribute is getting attached with the tag. But even after that the callback function is not getting called.

Any clue what am I missing? does it even work like this?

Any clue will be great

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

works fine like this:

```
<g:plusone size="tall" href="http://example.com"></g:plusone>
```

and js

```
var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
var gplus_event = document.getElementsByTagName("g:plusone");
if(gplus_event!=null)
{
     console.log(gplus_event);
     var x = document.getElementsByTagName("g:plusone");
     x[0].setAttribute('callback', 'plusone_vote');
     console.log(gplus_event);    
}
function plusone_vote(par) {
    alert(par.state);
}
```

Deno:: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hS68T/)

Comment: This won't work in all situations. There happens to be just of enough of a delay that your code is executing first, but I wouldn't count on that in all situations.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Sudhir works because there happens to be just enough of a delay the loading of the script, but it won't be guaranteed to work in all cases or possibly when the benefits of caching come into play.

The `plusone.js` file is parsing the page and rendering/transforming elements before your code is executed, so you're callback is being added too late. You will need to ensure that you attach your callback prior to this rendering of elements. You can do this in a couple methods.

1. [Use explicit rendering of tags.](https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/#example-explicit-render) and then call `gapi.plusone.render(elementId)` or `gapi.plusone.go(container)` to instruct the API that you're ready for the buttons to be used.
2. [Load the Google+ JavaScript asynchronously](https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/#example-async-load) after your code has executed.
3. Create your +1 buttons completely dynamically and call `gapi.plusone.render(elementId)` or `gapi.plusone.go(container)` when they are ready to transform.

Comment: You are right. I went into this problem. Finally I have abandoned this idea and I am attaching the call back statically actually. If I get some time I will come back to it. I am pretty much under pressure for this now!!